# Obtaining image from other website on server

Tags: php, html, image

I have two websites on a hosted server with hostgator.
I have website1 which is a website I built to add products, images, and track data from all the website we run. In this website I store the images in the filesystem on the server spot dedicated to this website.

Then I have website2 which is a website for to display a web store we are operating and I have it connect to the database that stores the data from website1 and grabs all the relative paths to the images that are on website1 filesystem. I cannot however get the browser to find these images and display them. It keeps giving me errors image not found.

I'm new to filesystem management using php and its proving to be a little difficult.

I am using this to set the file path to the image on website2.

```
src='".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/website1/public_html/$productIMG'
```

is there something else I have to do to get it to grab the image and display it or is it even possible to try to do what I am trying to do. Maybe I am missusing the $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] someone please help me.

The variable in the path is correct for the path I am trying find but the beginning part is not finding the correct way to the other website.

[Here](http://host/usr/local/apache/htdocs/website1/public_html/images/company/fd-6000-sliding.jpg) is an example of the link I am getting to an image.

Comment: The highlighting should give you a hint, the text `'DOCUMENT_ROOT'` is closing the starting single quote. It seems like you are meaning to wrap the text inside double quotes.

Comment: its not closing them it is concat'd into the src. The problem isnt the syntax I know that very well. I just dont know why its not returning the image of the website1 to show up on website2. It shows a file path but its not the correct one.

Comment: You are mixing website paths (e.g. "www.example.com/assets/image.png") with the actual path on the server (e.g. "/var/www/website2/assets/image.png"). The latter is useful for PHP on the server itself but not meant to be shown publicly. Try to find out the website path rather than the actual file path.

Comment: @Jan I dont know if I understand your answer. The image does not exist in the website path (website2). The image only resides in the website1 filesystem. No of this will be available for people see once I am done with the overall project I just cannot get the image to show up for testing purposes.

Comment: @AlexBeyer: Why not call it with website1's domain name?

Comment: so like www.website1.com/images/imagename?

Comment: @Jan This isnt working its prepends the host ip address to the front and wont find the image could you post and example?

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. I had to relative path all the way to the other file system on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A website cannot take the document root of another website and use it as its source. Website1 obviously has an address e.g www.website1.com. This is the public address that equates to its document root (public_html directory). In order to extract anything from there, you need to `www.website1.com/somefolder/somefile.extension` from Website2 or anywhere else. That won't let you down.